# How to add emoticon in TextView in Android

Tags: android, image, textview, emoticons

I tired for search long time for how to add emoticon in textview .
please if you have better sample please give me. or no please help for design .

Answer (score 1):

check out [ImageSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html) class. some example [HERE](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/)